# how can you filedialogbox to display a selected image in that specified window

Tags: python, tkinter

i have tried this code to dispaly an image on a canvas by using `open1` fuction call
    ....is this possible to do this....as every time i have tried ,it show given below errors

> **Errors**
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" C:/Users/suhel/PycharmProjects/steography.py/main.py
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:/Users/suhel/PycharmProjects/steography.py/main.py", line 16, in open1
>     photo=PhotoImage(file=img)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
>     Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
>     self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/suhel/PycharmProjects/steography.py/rotated.png' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>": 
>     no such file or directory
> ```

**THIS is my code**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk
import cv2
import tkinter
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

# **this is open fuction that allow to open a windows and 
# select an image,i have tried to used used Canvas to display the image 
# in the window,but it only display an empty window**    

def open1():
    img=filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/",title="select file",filetypes=(("image files",".png"),("all files","*py")))
    r1=Tk()
    canvas=Canvas(width=400,bg='blue')
    photo=PhotoImage(file=img)
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=photo,anchor=NW)
    canvas.pack()
    r1.mainloop()


#main window
root=Tk()
#string var
ans1=StringVar

root.title(" Steganography")

label=Label(root,text="Image Based Steganography",anchor="center",fg="#7cd36b",bg="#000000")
label.pack()
f=Font(label,label.cget("font"))
f.config(family="Helvetica",size=15,weight="bold",underline=True)
label.configure(font=f)

entry=Entry(root,font=("Helvetica 16 bold italic"),insertwidth=4,width=50,textvariable=ans1)
entry.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

top=Frame(root)
choose=Button(top,text="Open",fg="#7cd36b",width=13,font=("Helvetica 10 bold italic"),bd=5,command=open1)
choose.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=6,pady=5)
get=Button(top,text="get",fg="#7cd36b",width=13,font=("Helvetica 10 bold italic"),bd=5)#,command=lambda:option())
get.grid(row=1,column=2)
top.configure(background="#000000")
top.pack()

root.configure(background="#000000")
root.geometry("350x400+400+400")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop) and First you have to understand [Event-Driven Programming](http://eventdrivenpgm.sourceforge.net/)